# WiFi connected but network icon in the Pixel menu bar says; 'No wireless interfaces found'

Tags: wifi, pi-4, raspbian-buster, pixel

the network icon in the Pixel menu bar says no wireless, however WiFi is connected and working, or so it seems.  It's not a massive deal as it's actually working - I'd just like to be able to use the Pixel Desktop to change WiFi settings.

[image]

iwgetid and ifconfig seem to show Wifi is connected just fine.

OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) armv7l 
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1 
Kernel: 4.19.97-v7l+ 
CPU: BCM2835 (4) @ 1.500GHz 
Memory: 1340MiB / 3956MiB

edit; suggestion about DHCPCD, I don't recall having done anything to break it, it seems OK going by systemctl status;

[image: systemctl-DHCPCD-status]

Comment: You presumably have done something to break dhcpcd but as you have provided no details of what you did who knows

Comment: [Pixel is DEAD, Long Live RPD](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=161246&start=175#p1183248)

Comment: @Milliways thanks, the name change passed me by somehow, RPD it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the desktop tool and re-installing it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove wpagui
sudo apt install wpagui
```

To start it

```
sudo wpa_gui
```

My Buster box currently reports:

```
wpagui/stable 2:2.7+git20190128+0c1e29f-6+deb10u1 armhf
```

Not sure if this will help or make it worse so please have a backup of the SD card :-)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that didn't make any difference unfortunately